# Contact Form 7 auto added p tags

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have next code inside contact form 7 editor

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                [text* name class:border-field placeholder "Name"]
            </div><!-- End of col -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                [email* email class:border-field placeholder "Email"]
            </div><!-- End of col -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                [text subject class:border-field placeholder "Subject"]
            </div><!-- End of col -->
        </div><!-- ENd of row -->
    </div><!-- End of col -->
</div><!-- ENd of row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        [textarea message class:border-field placeholder "Message"]
    </div>
</div><!-- End of row -->

<div class="row text-center">
    <div clas s="col-sm-12">    
        [submit class:btn class:btn-black-fill class:btn-small "Submit"]  
    </div><!-- End of col -->
</div><!-- End of row -->
```

The problem is that it adds random p tags almost after each element and also that first text field is for some reason little bit above other two fields when they should all be inline. And i think this is not css problem because previously i had this coded in plane HTML and all fields were inline so i think it must be something with contact form 7.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

According to the [Contact Form 7 Docs](http://contactform7.com/controlling-behavior-by-setting-constants/), you can disable "wpautop" for the plugin by placing the following constant in *wp-config.php*:

```
define( 'WPCF7_AUTOP', false );
```

Comment: @LuisBrazilva I'm not sure what you mean that it "does nothing" - placing this code in my root `wp-config.php` file suppressed the output as expected.

Comment: For those here in 2018, see skip405's answer to change this in functions.php https://stackoverflow.com/a/49025096/3596962

Comment: Thanks @Ian. I'll leave my original answer here, but would recommend using skip405's answer instead. I think it makes more sense to use a filter, now that one exists.

Comment: Wow I spent so much time digging around do_shortcode how the damn autop slips into it. Would not have thought that CF7 deliberately inserts them itself ....

Comment: Outdated solution, please refear next answer.

Answer (score 94):

If editing `wp-config.php` is not the solution for you, there's a handy filter. Put it in your `functions.php`:

```
// Remove <p> and <br/> from Contact Form 7
add_filter('wpcf7_autop_or_not', '__return_false');
```

Comment: This feature has been added to [version 5.0](https://contactform7.com/2018/01/31/contact-form-7-50/).

Answer (score 8):

I would like to say something about this, when we want reduce auto P tag form the we should go with below filter and just write blow code in function.php.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_autop_or_not', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried many answers but **nothing worked** so...
I ended up using simple CSS to specifically target empty P tags
in the form itself like this:

```
.wpcf7-form p:empty { display: none; }
```

This worked for me and, its a simple solution.

Comment: The answers,  using `filter` and `wp-config` should be the accepted ones, this is just a kludge.

Comment: But your answer removes all paragraph tags. that created a new problem in my case. The problem was that empty p tag created spacing (and blocking). This way you can handle an empty p tag (easily). Using this way you can target specific forms.

So, "kludge" or not ;). this works.

Comment: This will not work if cf7 generates ```<p>``` with ```<br>``` tags inside - so it is not entirely empty.

Comment: True, but that means you did some line breaks in your form code for the beauty of it. which I understand but isn't really necessary ... right? i think that if you don't want to completely remove the paragraphs in the form you should use this CSS solution. Otherwise using the hook offered by @skip405 is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your functions.php file

```
function reformat_auto_p_tags($content) {
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

add_filter('the_content', 'reformat_auto_p_tags', 99);
add_filter('widget_text', 'reformat_auto_p_tags', 99);
```

Then on your post editor wrap your contact form 7 shortcode with `raw` shortcode

e.g.

```
[raw][contact-form-7 id="1" title="Contact Us"][/raw]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too. Tested with WordPress 5.7, PHP 7.4, Contact Form 7 v5.4.

```php
<?php
add_filter('wpcf7_autop_or_not', false);
```

Potentially there are situations (old versions of WP, PHP?) where using the `__return_false` utility function is necessary.

Comment: I shared an alternate solution that is simpler and works, while acknowledging that there may be situations where it is not appropriate. This is completely in accordance with the guidelines of how to answer. If your comment was supposed to be constructive, you really need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I don't think that a long explanation of how wordpress filters work is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to remove auto added p tags

1st way is to add constant in `wp-config.php` file

```
define( 'WPCF7_AUTOP', false );
```

2nd way is to use filter hook. You can add this in `functions.php` or in the custom plugin.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_autop_or_not', '__return_false');
```