# Display Contact form 7 input directly on the form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to achieve the following, try searching here but to no avail.

I want to display the guest input directly in the form before hitting the submit button.

Example,
There are 2 questions, 
Input-A is date : 29/04/2019
Input-B is text : John

Number 3 will be a box where Input-A and Input-B will be display even before the guest click on submit button.

Example : 
Dear Input-B, your appointment will be on 29/04/2019.

=> will be

Dear John, your appointment will be on 29/04/2019.

Do I need to use DF7 dynamic extension? I'm new to dynamic text extension, how can I achieve using the dynamic text extension?

Comment: Is this what you were talking about?

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled with jQuery.  If you want to move the result, just put it where you want...

First in Contact Form 7. Do something like this.

```
<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label>Enter Date
    [date the-date]</label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

[submit "Send"]

<div id="result"></div>
```

And then you want to add this to your theme's js files.  If you disable auto-p https://stackoverflow.com/a/32540049/3821467 in CF7, then you can paste it directly into CF7 within `<script></script>`

```
(function($) {
    $('input[name="the-date"]').blur(function(){
        var name = $('input[name="your-name"]').val();
        var date = $('input[name="the-date"]').val();
        $('#result').html('<p>Dear ' + name + ', your appointment will be on ' + date + '.</p>');
    });
})( jQuery );
```

This only activates when blur is triggered after user puts in date and clicks to another field.  To change the trigger, or add another, you could include more jQuery to update after name changes or whatever.